# Why is PolynomialQ[y^2,x] True?

Tags: polynomials, expression-test

Why is `PolynomialQ[y^2,x]` `True`?  The documentation says `PolynomialQ[]` returns `True` only if the first argument is a polynomial in the variable(s) specified in the second argument.  There must be a nuance I don't get.

Comment: `y^2`  is a constant polynomial considered as a polynomial with respect to `x`, e.g. it is written  usually as $a_0$. When you write `PolynomialQ[y[x]^2, x]` you'll get false.

Comment: Thanks, Artes.  That makes sense.  Is there a way to identify polynomials using specific independent variables?  Say I have a list of polynomials, all of which use some combination of, say, three variables x, y and z.  The only way I know to eliminate the ones with, say, x, is not very elegant.  Is there an easy way to delete the polynomials I don't want based on which variables they use?  It's for an algebraic geometry course in which we're using polynomial partial ideals.

Comment: I guess you should ask another question. To adress problems unambiguously you have to demonstrate a piece of code that could be improved.

Comment: Thanks again, Artes.